# Instance of an abstract class

Tags: java

Couldy you clarify why this works:

```
public abstract class AbstractClassCreationTest {

    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("I'm the abstract class' instance!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractClassCreationTest acct = new AbstractClassCreationTest(){};
        acct.hello();
    }
}
```

I suppose it contradicts to the specification where we can find:

**It is a compile-time error if an attempt is made to create an instance of an abstract
class using a class instance creation expression (§15.9).**

Answer (score 21):

You may have not noticed the difference:

```
new AbstractClassCreationTest(){};
```

versus

```
new AbstractClassCreationTest();
```

**That extra `{}` is the body of a new, nameless class that extends the abstract class**. You have  created an instance of an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and not of an abstract class.

Now go ahead an declare an abstract method in the abstract class, watch how compiler forces you to implement it inside `{}` of anonymous class.

Answer (score 7):

Notice the difference between:

```
 AbstractClassCreationTest acct = new AbstractClassCreationTest(){};//case 1

 NonAbstractClassCreationTest acct = new NonAbstractClassCreationTest();//case 2
```

*case1* is an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) definition. You are *not* instantiating an abstract class; instead you are instantiating a *subType* of said abstract class.

Comment: When I declare an anonymous class, however I don't use an abstract class. I don't know if possible do it. I can't find anything on web and in your link there's no reference about link between abstract and anonymous class.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are not creating the object of the `AbstractClassCreationTest` class , actually you are creating an object of anonymous inner class who extends the `AbstractClassCreationTest` class.This is because you have written `new AbstractClassCreationTest(){} not new AbstractClassCreationTest()`
You can know more about anonymous inner class from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class cannot instantiated.

You must create an extension class extends an abstract class and so istantiated this new class.

```
public abstract class AbstractClassCreationTest {

    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("I'm the abstract class' instance!");
    }
}

public class MyExtClass extends AbstractClassCreationTest() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyExtClass acct = new MyExtClass(){};
    acct.hello();
}
```

I post [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). Can be useful for you. Have a nice day